# Jetty ProxyServlet: how to add HTTPS support?

Tags: java, ssl, groovy, proxy, jetty

I made a simple proxy server using the Jetty ProxyServlet. It works for http protocol. Below is my code (in groovy):

**MyProxyServlet**

```
class MyProxyServlet extends ProxyServlet {
    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger( this )

    @Override
    void init( ServletConfig config ) throws ServletException {
        super.init( config )
        logger.info('>>> init done!')
    }

    @Override
    void service( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) {
        logger.info('>>> got a request')
        super.service( request, response)
        response.addHeader('foo', 'bar')
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyProxyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.foobar.MyProxyServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyProxyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The code is wrapped into a war, root.war, and deployed into a Jetty server on my Mac with port 8080. Then I enabled `Web Proxy (HTTP)` and `Secure Web Proxy (HTTPS)` in the System Preferences of my Mac. As aforementioned, it works for http. However, for HTTPS, it doesn't work. So, how can I make it work with HTTPS?

BTW, according to this example ([Jetty ProxyServlet with SSL support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852056/jetty-proxyservlet-with-ssl-support)), it seems that I need to add a `ConnectHandler`, but I don't know how to achieve this in web.xml.

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you are writing this new code against Jetty 9 or Servlet 3.1, then it is *strongly advised* that you use `AsyncProxyServlet` (as the normal ProxyServlet is only for migrated code from servlet 2.5)